# Acyclicity of co-chain complexes in terms of quasi-isomorphisms.

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Weibel gives equivalent conditions for acyclicity of chain complexes, one of which is that the chain complex map $0\to C_.$ is a quasi-isomorphism (i.e. $H_n(0)=0\to H_n(C_.)$ is an isomorphism). While proving the converse, I only used the surjectivity of $H_n(0)=0\to H_n(C_.)$ to get $H_n(C_.)=0$ for all $n$.

Since co-chain complexes are 'dual' to chain complexes, I believe one must reverse all the arrows starting from a chain complex to get a co-chain complex. So, should the condition be like this:

$C^.$ is acyclic $\iff$ $C^.\to 0$ is a quasi-isomorphism

(here one needs injectivity of $H_n(C_.)\to H_n(0)=0$ for the converse).

Or, would it also be fine if condition is like this:

$C^.$ is acyclic $\iff$ $0\to C^.$ is a quasi-isomorphism.

Or does it not matter at all? I am super new to category theory and homological algebra and would like to learn concepts behind what I am writing down as clearly as possible. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't matter because those conditions are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you :)) In this case, I had thought just as much. However what about in general, how to meaningfully reverse arrows? Weibel says to go from $C_.$ to $C^.$ we should take $C^n:=C_{-n}$. Is there something similar to get co-chain complex maps from chain complex maps (if at all this makes sense).

Comment: You don't need to reverse all the arrows. The categories of chain complexes and cochain complexes (indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$) are literally isomorphic (not just equivalent), not opposites or anything like that. The only difference is that the indices increase for one of them and decrease for the other. Of course usually one indexes by $\mathbb{N}$ and then there are some differences.

Comment: I see. Thank you :))